Power Automate: how execute Anaconda ambient
I want to execute py files using Anaconda ambient. I can't open Powershell prompt to send command line. Have you suggestions?
Solution, 1 not working: execute powershell flow with command:
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Users\andre\anaconda3' "

Solution 2 not working: execute dos command flow to execute powershell:
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\Users\andre\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Users\andre\anaconda3' "

I tried the solutions 1 and 2 without success. I also tried past solutions in StackOverflow.I hope to have suggestions to complete flow process and execeute py file in Conda .

my solution is execute shell commands from Automate:
conda info --envs
conda activate envname

